# ACM sigconf not working in new template 2017

Tags: errors, acm

I am trying to prepare my article with the new ACM template available [Here](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). When I compile I get the following errors everytime. That means, that these commands are not recognized by tex or the class file which they are calling `acmart.dtx` is not linked properly.

Errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \acmDOI 
            {10.475/123_4}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
```

There are many such errors. Kindly, help me.

**Edits:**

I downloaded the zip file from the link pointed above. Then I extracted the files to the acmart folder. It contained `acmart.dtx`, and few other tex files for sig conferences, journals and the file `sigconf.tex`.

Now, I compiled the `sigconf.tex` file to get the errors specified above.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a complete  MWE example?   I do not have problems with the new `acmart` class.

Comment: You should first of all unpack the files. Do `tex acmart.ins`.

Comment: @Guido Is the acmart.dtx a class file. It has been used like this: \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart} But, there is no acmart.cls file. Should I download it from other source.

Comment: Do what egreg said.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. It worked! I did tex acmart.ins

Comment: In addition to @egreg's correct comment, note that there is a Makefile included which can be used to extract the derived files, e.g. `make acmart.cls`.

Comment: After running `tex acmart.ins` it all started working for me, I didn't know what an ins file was for. This question contains more information about .ins files for further research: [What's the point of INS and DTX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344530/whats-the-point-of-ins-and-dtx-files). In particular, [this page](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/dtxins.html) cleared up the confusion for me.

Comment: how can we run 'tex acmart.ins' in TexStudio???

Comment: @VinodKumarChauhan probably easier to just run it from the command prompt (just type `tex acmart.ins`), you may need to add your TeX installation folder to your system path. I use TeXStudio on my system and it worked fine after running the command.

Answer (score 11):

OSX 10.11 here. Running `tex acmart.ins` using TeXShop fails with errors. Fortunately, I found the missing `acmart.cls` file on the SIGPLAN website:

http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls

I wonder why ACM didn't include it in the zip archive.

Comment: It is automatically generated after compiling ins file. Tex acmart.ins

Comment: In case for whatever reason `tex` is not available as command, for instance when using ShareLateX, this is the only viable way.

Comment: @Coder but it doesnt work for me. WinEdt still looks for `acmart.cls`

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar variety of errors, including an error for the `\orcid` line. My solution included one extra step.

I followed the directions of the comments and run `tex acmart.ins`. The errors persisted. But! If I then delete all the files of the form `sample-sigconf.*` except the `sample-sigconf.tex` source file would build.

Answer (score 2):

[`acmart`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) is distributed also on CTAN and as package for MiKTeX and also for TeX Live. So you should use the package manager of your TeX distribution to install it. The default installation of vanilla TeX Live 2017 already contains `acmart`. If you have not used the default installation, you can use

```
tlmgr install acmart
```

to install it. If only `root` can install packages, you need

```
sudo tlmgr install acmart
```

For MiKTeX [use the MiKTeX package manager](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html).

Answer (score 1):

I also just had the same problem and I get several `Undefined control sequence` errors when I build&view the sample-sigconf.tex in Ubuntu with Textstudio. It turns out that `samplebody-conf.tex` contains some figures with the command `\Description`, like:

> \begin{figure}\includegraphics{fly}\Description{A fly}\caption{A sample black and white graphic.}\end{figure}.

The `\Description` command was not recognized. I tried executing `tex acmart.ins` in the command line and removing the `sample-sigconf.*` files as suggested above, but nothing worked. The example images are provided both in `eps` format to work with Latex and `pdf` format to work with Pdflatex. I tried different build commands chains, and I realized that DVI->PS and PS->PDF actually overlooked the `\Description` command and building the tex file worked.

As a solution, I just removed all descriptions, since they are not necessary for the figures and captions are enough.
The ACM [template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) was updated on November 11th 2018, which might have introduced this error.