# \authornotemark "Undefined control sequence."

Tags: compilation-error, author, undefined

After downloading [this acmart.cls](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acmccs/format/master/acmart.cls) file, and the `sample-sigconf.tex` from [the ACM Primary Article Template](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-primary.zip) I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-
dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.127 \authornotemark
                      [1]
?
```

when I compile the file with:

```
pdflatex sample-sigconf.tex
```

So I tried including:

```
\def\@authornotemark{\g@addto@macro\@currentauthors{\footnotemark\relax}}
\@@authornotemark
```

which did not resolve the error.

How can I resolve this compilation error?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357952/161901). I had to include/copy the files in the unzipped folder `acmart-primary` into the same folder as the `sample-sigconf.tex`, and then run:

```
tex acmart.ins
```

I also had to copy the following files into the root of my directory:

```
acmart.cls
sampleteaser.pdf
sample-franklin.png
```