# Best way to include an "enriched" version of a course

Tags: formatting

I’m learning to be a teacher, and I’m preparing a document which is a course for school students.
I get evaluated by more experienced teachers on my work and my pedagogic skills. My course must give them extra information that

1. my students shall not see
2. my teachers can conveniently read, together with the course, to get more information about why/how I organise the course in a certain way

At first, I considered writing double-page PDF: All rectos containing student course, all versos with pedagogic and extra comments.
This way, if I print only pair pages and I get the students-version of my course! Printing all pages recto-verso will give a richer view, on each « verso » page, about the content on the next recto.

Doing this manually is very cumbersome though: I need to finish courses pages manually (clearpage), then include pedagogic notes, then clearpage again to continue the course. If I must add extra content that goes beyond 1 page, all my pages logic has to be re-thought.

Would you be so kind to recommend methods where I can concentrate on writing my course, just including my extra pedagogic notes, and be able to « hide » them from my students while a more « full » version is available for my teachers?
Is manual page breaks the only option? Envisage some footnotes formats that can be put « aside » and enabled/disabled?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Have a look at the [`comment` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment).

Comment: What document class are you using?  Beamer has \notes built in (see Creating Supporting Material starting on page 195).  For other document classes you can use paracol to create a 2 page layout using \switchcolumn (between paragraphs) to add notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New Version (teacher's notes on separate pages)

I used `newfile` package to write the text for teacher's comments (that are given in the `teachersonlyBox` environment) into a separate file `\jobname.teachers`. Its content is inserted with the command `\instertteacherspages` and puts it on a separate page using `\clearpage` before and afterwards. It is also possible to have multiple pages of teacher notes (see example below). Of course, you could also just use the `\instertteacherspages` only one time at the end to insert all notes at once to the end.

You could also define other things than boxes, like I did in the old version below.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{teachers}

\newtoggle{teachersversion}
\toggletrue{teachersversion} % comment out for students version

\iftoggle{teachersversion}{%
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.teachers}{teachers}
    \NewEnviron{teachersonlyBox}{
        \addtostream{teachers}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[
                colframe = red!20,
                colback  = red!10,
                coltitle = black,
                title = {comment for teachers},
            ]
                \BODY
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }
    }
}{
    \NewEnviron{teachersonlyBox}{}
}

\newcommand{\instertteacherspages}{
    \iftoggle{teachersversion}{%
        \closeoutputstream{teachers}
        \clearpage
        \input{\jobname.teachers}
        \clearpage
        \openoutputfile{\jobname.teachers}{teachers}
    }{%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{teachersonlyBox}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{teachersonlyBox}

\lipsum[3-5]

\begin{teachersonlyBox}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{teachersonlyBox}

\instertteacherspages

\lipsum[6-7]

\begin{teachersonlyBox}
    \lipsum[8-11]
\end{teachersonlyBox}

\lipsum[8]

\begin{teachersonlyBox}
    \lipsum[9]
\end{teachersonlyBox}

\instertteacherspages

\end{document}
```

#### Result

teacher's version:

[image]

student's version:

[image]

### Old Version (teacher's notes inbetween)

A simple way to do this, is to define a command for the text blocks of the teacher's version `\teachersonly` and change the definition depending on what version you want.
It might be useful to use some highlighting for that like a color or a box, so I used red text in the example.

I also added a `teachersonlyBox` environment that adds a box around the text with `tcolorbox`. I used `comment` package to exclude environment content if necessary.

Or use a `\teachersfootnote` to make a footnote only visible for teachers.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtoggle{teachersversion}
\toggletrue{teachersversion} % comment out for students version

\iftoggle{teachersversion}{%
    \newcommand{\teachersonly}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    \newenvironment{teachersonlyBox}{
        \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colframe = red!20,
            colback  = red!10,
            coltitle = black,
            title = {comment for teachers},
        ]
    }{
        \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    \newcommand{\teachersfootnote}[1]{%
        \textcolor{red}{\footnote{\textcolor{red}{teacher's note: #1}}}%
    }
}{%
    \usepackage{comment}
    \newcommand{\teachersonly}[1]{}
    \excludecomment{teachersonlyBox}
    \newcommand{\teachersfootnote}[1]{}
}

\begin{document}

visible for all

\teachersonly{comments for teachers}

visible for all\teachersfootnote{foo}

\teachersonly{comments for teachers}

\begin{teachersonlyBox}
    comments for teachers
    comments for teachers
\end{teachersonlyBox}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

teachers version:

[image]

student's version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks nice and is extremely handy! The boxes look great, I'd even consider having several box types. Only thing is that the space it takes can still be quite significant. Do you have any idea how the teachers sections can be (as I said, I hope it's correct) "put aside", below, on a different page, ... ?

Comment: So you want to write teacher's text just anywhere at the latex document and gather it to show it on a separate page? Two options: (1) gather everything and show it at the end, or (2) gather something and show it when a command is triggered at the next page (e.g., `<text> <teacher's text> <text> <teacher's text> \showteacherstextonnextpage <text> ...`).

Comment: Indeed, and I think that showing it at the end (or at the bottom of the page) would be ideal...

Comment: I added `\teachersfootnote` for making footnotes for teachers that are visible on the bottom of the page. To gather text and write it later, you would have to write it to an external file and load it later.

Comment: I added a new version with teacher's notes on separate pages.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend a different solution. Generally, `.tex` format is not a very good source format (because you cannot properly parse it without TeX). So, if you need two `.pdf`s, you need two `.tex`-files.
My personal recommendation is the following: store the information in a different format, say `.xml` or `.dtx` (see the example below), and then use them to produce two different `.tex`-files, which are then compiled separately.

**Example with `.dtx`:** `.dtx` is a `.tex`-format file that can be used to produce multiple source files. You can find more [in this TUG article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92pakin.pdf), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344530/whats-the-point-of-ins-and-dtx-files), [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/dtxins.html) and more information in Google.

**Step 1.** Create a file called `enr.dtx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Problem 1.} What is ${ 2+2 }$?

% \iffalse
%<*teacher>
% \fi
  \textbf{Answer.} 4.
  
% \iffalse
%</teacher>
% \fi
\textbf{Problem 2.} What is ${ 3 + 3 }$?

% \iffalse
%<*teacher>
% \fi
  \textbf{Answer.} 6.
  
% \iffalse
%</teacher>
% \fi
% \iffalse
%<*stud>
% \fi
  This is something only the students will see.
% \iffalse
%</stud>
% \fi
\end{document}

%\Finale
```

Everything surrounded by the tags `<*teacher>...</teacher>` will be visible only to the teacher.

**Step 2.** Create a file `enr.ins`:

```
\input l3docstrip

\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse

\generate{\file{\jobname-stud.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{stud}}}

\generate{\file{\jobname-teacher.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{teacher}}}

\endbatchfile
```

**Step 3.** Run the `.ins` file like this: `pdftex enr.ins`.
This will produce two files: `enr-teacher.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Problem 1.} What is ${ 2+2 }$?

  \textbf{Answer.} 4.

\textbf{Problem 2.} What is ${ 3 + 3 }$?

  \textbf{Answer.} 6.

\end{document}
```

and `enr-stud.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Problem 1.} What is ${ 2+2 }$?

\textbf{Problem 2.} What is ${ 3 + 3 }$?

  This is something only the students will see.
\end{document}
```

Note that I have omitted some comments from the file.

**Step 4.** Now compile the two `.tex` files like you normally would.

**Notes.** This may be a bit complicated if you are new to TeX, but would really recommend and approach similar to this one.
You can also use `.xml` or `.html` file formats and then process them using e. g. Python library called `Beautiful Soup`

Comment: "Generally, .tex format is not a very good source format" - That's a strange statement that I would disagree with. You don't need two tex files to create two pdf files, if you use variables as in my answer. It could also be automated by using a shell script that compiles the tex file multiple times with different variables set. As long as you do not need the two source files (as tex) but only the resulting pdfs, I think the approach of using a dtx file is overkill. If you need two separate source files, the approach is fine.

Comment: A big thanks, that’s very interesting and I’ll try it out! Additionally, is there a way to use footnotes but just include/exclude them on demand (toggle?)

Comment: @dexteritas I wanted to say that it is difficult to extract information from a .tex file. Much easier to do it with .xml or .dtx file.

Comment: @Gauffke Do you want to have two pdfs: one with footnotes and one without? If yes, you can use a similar approach.